# Richard Pavliceks mystery

Tags: bridge, puzzles

Richard Pavlicek made a great bridge site.

Here

http://www.rpbridge.net/7f55.htm

The mystery is this:

> Is there a bridge hand where North/South can make a grandslam in any
>   suit, but not even make 5NT?

he asks for solving a mystery and how close he came to a solution. He claims he first saw it in a newspaper.

I am also very interested in this task.

Does anyone know a solution or, better yet the deal Richard Pavlicek might have seen in the newspaper??

Comment: Please revise your question to include the mystery, that way if the link goes down your question is still valuable. Leave the link of course for reference and explaining his solutions, but the original question should be in-line here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not really about the problem discussed by Pavlicek, but rather a reference request that is probably non existent.

Comment: @Guvante: Any quote of the problem sufficient to get people started would likely go beyond the limits of *fair usage*, and thus unfortunately violate copyright.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: What copyright? Pavlicek clearly states he found it elsewhere. Just quoting the problem will not violate fair usage even if (but IANAL). And this is clearly on-topic and actually one of the more objective questions I have seen about bridge on this site.

Comment: It is the same thing as in this question : http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23788/par-zero-deal-with-many-points-for-n-s

Comment: The difficulty of answering a question is no criterion for off-topic or on-topic. It is important that a concrete answer is possible. And I do not see how a creation of a board with pavlicek's properties violates the copyright, unless the constructed problem happens to be exactly the same as the unknown author published.